# Creating a list of symbols in latex

Tags: latex, macros, lookup-tables

I'm trying to get an auto generated list of symbols in my latex project. Here is the macro that I have so far...

```
\newcommand{\addsymbol}[3]{%
  \symboldisplay{#1}{#2}\\%
  \setelem{#3}{#1}
}
\newcommand{\symboldisplay}[2]{%
  $#1$ \parbox{5in}{\dotfill #2}%
}

\def\setelem#1{\expandafter\def\csname myarray(#1)\endcsname}
\def\dispsymbol#1{\csname myarray(#1)\endcsname}
```

I then include my list of symbols like so

```
\begin{listofsymbols}
\input{symbols}
\end{listofsymbols}
```

where the symbols.tex file is

```
\addsymbol{n}{Number of sample points}{num_points}
\addsymbol{f_s}{Sampling frequency}{samp_frequency}
```

I can then get my symbol by label like so: \dispsymbol{num_points} -- this displays n in this case.

This works all find and dandy... when I am calling \dispsymbol in the same chapter (the List of Symbols chapter) as the \addsymbol def. When I try to get the label for the symbol in another chapter nothing seems to work.

Could anyone help me, or suggest a package that will do what I am looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is that

```
\begin{listofsymbols} 
\end{listofsymbols}
```

is the scope and any macro is lost after this group. You should define the global macros.
Replace the following

```
\def\setelem#1{\expandafter\def\csname myarray(#1)\endcsname}
```

with

```
\def\setelem#1{\expandafter\gdef\csname myarray(#1)\endcsname}
```

Answer (score 5):

To automatically generate a list of symbols you can use the [nomencl](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nomencl/) package, or for more complex documents that requires also glossaries or lists of acronyms, the [glossaries](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/glossaries.html) package.

Check the examples in the documentation ;)

Comment: I have looked at nomencl and it looks good, but the other code dose what I want. Plus i get to say I wrote it mostly by myself :)

Thanks